# Is it possible to bind [Compose] + [`] + [`] to type “ (opening double quote)?

Tags: compose-key

I know I can type the opening quote using `[Compose]` + `[<]` + `["]`, but that's quite cumbersome. I'd like to rebind relatively often typed sequences so that they are easier to reach.

In my `.XCompose` I added lines

```
<Multi_key> <grave> <grave>             : "“"
<Multi_key> <grave> <dead_grave>        : "“"
<Multi_key> <grave> <grave> <dead_grave>: "“"
```

but neither seems to help, as two times "grave" key after `[Compose]` is still not bound. Best I managed is to bind it to `[grave]` `[1]` instead:

```
<Multi_key> <grave> <1>                 : "“"
```

That's easy enough to type, but still **is it possible to bind `[Compose]` + `[grave]` + `[grave]` to type “ (opening double quote)?**

On a related note, is it possible to force `~/.XCompose` reload without full restart of X server?